# How to include xml attribute with blank value when using XmlSerializer in c#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, xmlserializer

I have a class like this

```
public class Information
{
    [XmlAttribute("fullname")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("age")]
    public int? Age { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("joiningdate")]
    public DateTime? JoiningDate { get; set; }
}
```

when I have value in all members of class like :

```
Name = ABC
Age = 15
JoiningDate = 2016-01-22T13:17:51+05:30
```

with above data it's serialize perfectly.

but when I have null value in any member of class it's skip attribute to write in XML. But I want attribute with same name with blank value.

If I have this type of data :

```
Name = ABC
Age = null
JoiningDate = null
```

In XmlSerializer now I got xml like below  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Information fullname="ABC">
</Information>
```

**But I want this type of XML after Serialize :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Information fullname="ABC" age="" joiningdate="">
</Information>
```

Comment: Hi.. Are you allowed to change the datatypes of the serializeable class?

Comment: NO, datatype are fixed

Comment: If you could turn your attributes into elements, you could use [XmlElementAttribute.IsNullable Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable(v=vs.110).aspx). If you are stuck with implementing [IXmlSerializable Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx) yourself. (see linked posts under *Related*)

Comment: @Filburt - Doesn't that write out xsi:nil = "true" in the XML? OP wants it to equal blank. -- Not that I have an answer! :)

Comment: Yes, `XmlElementAttribute.IsNullable Property` worked with elements but I must need data in XML attributes.

Comment: @RajuPatel - All I can suggest to do is to replace the default time stamp and age zero with blanks in xml string after its been serialized

Comment: @Wheels73 - When I deserialize and send data back to database it's store that default value but we don't want change database data format.

Comment: @RajuPatel - Can you say what the larger problem is with those attributes being the XML? I'm don't think you can do what you need to do with the types in the serializeable class!

Comment: after save data in xml I directly deal with the xml attributes. So, attributes must need to their with valid value or blank value.